# Brick breaker game not updating from unbroken to broken brick after being hit by ball

Tags: javascript, game-development

I have 2 png files with a unbroken brick and a broken brick which I want to show after the first collision with a ball.

The game is designed to draw the bricks at the start of the level and then filter out the bricks that have been hit twice. Every update should redraw the bricks that are still in the game, but I have modified my draw function to include a switch statement that should display either the broken or unbroken brick depending on if it has been hit, but it is not working.

It seems that the draw function doesn't respond to the switch statement, because I have tried changing the boolean values to see if I can have the game just draw the broken brick, but it still displays the unbroken brick.

I can get the broken brick to show only when I eliminate the switch statement and drawImage with this.brickBroken.

my brick.js file is separate from game.js, so I might be missing some detail that communicates to the game.js file that it needs to display the broken brick, but it seems that I should be able to update the displayed png brick file from the draw function in brick.js.

What am I missing?

Here is the relevant brick.js file.

draw(ctx) {

```
    switch (this.hitBrick) {
        case true:
            ctx.drawImage(
                this.brickBroken, 
                this.position.x,
                this.position.y,
                this.width, 
                this.height);

        case false: 
        ctx.drawImage(
            this.brickUnbroken, 
            this.position.x,
            this.position.y,
            this.width, 
            this.height); 
    }
}







update(deltaTime) {
    if(detectCollision(this.game.ball, this )) {
        this.game.ball.speed.y = - this.game.ball.speed.y;

        if (this.hitBrick === true) this.markedForDeletion = true;

        this.hitBrick = true;

    }

}
```

Comment: Honestly if you are only checking for two things a switch statement isn't worth the hassle, might as well use an if else and draw it there or if you want to shorten the code a conditional opperator within the ctx.drawImage checking if the brick is broken or not, which may help solve your problem. However, from the looks of things the issue is with how you detect whether a brick is broken or not

Comment: The conditional operator worked! I still don't understand why the switch statement doesn't work, because they both say the same thing right? If I say this.hitBrick ? ctx.drawImage(this.brickBroken...) : ctx.drawImage(this.brickUnbroken...), is it not the same as switch (this.hitBrick) case true : ctx.drawImage(this.brickBroken...); case false : ctx.drawImage(this.brickUnbroken...)?

Comment: Can you include the code which determines whether `this.hitBrick`Also, the other image for `this.brickUnbroken` could be loaded wrong or have the wrong path. Could you double check that please

Comment: this.hitBrick is declared in the constructor of the Brick class and is initialized to false. In the update(deltaTime) method, if there is a collision then this.hitBrick is set to true. Once it is true, the draw(ctx) method will draw brickBroken, and if the same brick is hit again (i.e. this.hitBrick === true) then this.markedForDeletion is set to true. In game.js, if the brick is markedForDeletion, then it is filtered out of the bricks array in game.js. So on the next update, any brick markedForDeletion is not redrawn. Hopefully that makes sense.